# How can I change the stroke Width of my SVG Path with a Input Box

Tags: javascript, html, svg, snap.svg

I am creating a SVG Path for my Website. Now I want a input box where i can say for example the strokeWidth should be 10 and when i click the button this value should be used by the Path. Is this possible ?  Down below you can see the code of my input Box and the Button to set the Width + the code of my SVG Path. Now I am asking you guys how i can connect them.

```
<input type="number" placeholder="StrokeWidth" id="WidthBox"></input>
<input type="button" name="setStroke" id="setStroke" value="set Stroke"></input>
```

```
var L_PUF_WAR = s.path("m 338.57052,275.31046 v 110.41789 h 95.11902 v 39.24491"
                 .attr({
                        fill: "none",
                        stroke: "#bada55",
                        strokeWidth: 15
                    });
```

Comment: Get the value of the `<input>`, and put it in the `strokeWidth`?  `strokeWidth: $('#myInput').val()`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I get the value of text input field using JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11563638/how-do-i-get-the-value-of-text-input-field-using-javascript)

Comment: I also tried the other tutorial but nothing worked. And your method is also not working. Is it possible that nothing is working because the Path gets created in a onload function?

Comment: the only command that didn't seem to screw up the whole svg was this one ```document.getElementById("WidthBox").value``` On every other command i got a complete blank page and on this only my path disapears so i think this one could work out but i don't know how

Comment: ` Is it possible that nothing is working because the Path gets created in a onload function`. Just modify the `strokeWidth` attribute even if the path is already rendered. `$('#myPath').attr('strokeWidth', value)`

Comment: It is not working, all my other SVG elements disappear and only the path gets displayed but i cant even change the value of that so nothing is working